# Книги по Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, книги, zend-framework-2

Доброго дня!
Ищется литература по Zend Framework 2 с уклоном на практику.
Спасибо всем.

Comment: В связи с тем что zf2 зарелизилась сравнительно недавно, большого выбора литературы вы не найдёте.

Answer (score 1):

http://zendframework.ru/forum/index.php?topic=6797.0
На все вопросы даст ответ иероглиф :)

Comment: Было бы не плохо продублировать ссылки в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

[книги](http://zendframework.ru/links/books)
но я предпочитаю документацию, смотрим на том же сайте.

Некоторые книги можно скачать на сайте миркниг

[с Озона русские](http://www.ozon.ru/?context=search&text=Zend+Framework)

[и еще с Озона](http://www.ozon.ru/?context=search&text=Zend+Framework)

Answer (score 0):

Книги в [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_8?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=zend%20framework%202&sprefix=zend+fra%2Caps%2C438),
а потом поиск в [bookfi](http://bookfi.org/) или в гугле